# Unlinking vertices/edges/faces in Blender

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, workflow

I have an object that I'm trying to edit in Blender and unlink all possible connected faces of the same selected.

So, bottom line, my issue is:

- I have an object and add it in Blender. Then, I am selecting a face/vertex of a specific part of that object;
- To select all linked, I'm using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (as shown in the image below - the SCREW on the left side);
- As you can also see shown in the image, the SCREW on the right side has not been selected - therefore I assume it is not linked to SCREW on the left side and no need to unlink;
- However, if I open the same object in another 3D software (i.e.: Substance Painter) and I'd like to fill in with a color the SCREW on the left side, that color is applied also to the SCREW on the right side and yet, they seem not to be linked in Blender.

[image]

What am I missing here? Is there any way I can achieve this? I would like to unlink these two and to be able to fill them with different colors. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> you only do a selection of linked vertices. What you need is to unlink the materials. You probably have one material on both screws, you need to select one screw and apply another material to it.

You can also probably adjust your UV map so the UV maps of the screws are not overlapping, this way you can use the same material on both screws.

[image]

[image]